# Get all matches in text which start with specific string and is between parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

So i found regex here that finds text between parentheses:

```
preg_match_all('/\(((?:[^\(\)]++|(?R))*)\)/', $string, $matches)
```

this works fine. Problem is when i add that text which i want to start with: `preg_match_all('/(text)\(((?:[^\(\)]++|(?R))*)\)/', $string, $matches)`
then it only works with string like this:

```
text(some text between parentheses and starting with "text")
```

but i need it to work with a string like this too:

```
text(some text between parentheses (more text between parentheses) and starting with "text")
```

as far as i could figure it out, problem is with this part (?R) (recursive), but I'm not sure how to change this regex to work with the string I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to this:

```
$re = '/text ( \( (?: [^()]* | (?-1) )* \) )/x';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KfrzdI/1)

Text between brackets is available in group #1.

`(?-1)` in PCRE is back-reference of previous numbered captured group.

---

**Update:**

As per comment below OP wants to capture text between parentheses but without capturing parentheses. This regex should work:

```
$re = '/text ( \( ( (?: [^()]* | (?-2) )* ) \) )/x';
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/KfrzdI/2)

Check captured group #2 for your text between parentheses.

Comment: Is `(?-1)` the same as `\1`?

Comment: No it is not. `(?-1)` is relative back-reference that is `current number  - 1`th group while `\1` is always back-reference for group #1

Comment: Thank you! One small thing though, previously I had #2 group where match was without starting and ending parentheses, but now there is no #2 group and in #1 group match is between parentheses, is it possible to get that match without parentheses?